# Gather class attributes of elements for a class summary

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Given the following XML

```
<stuff>
  <div>
    <p class="A">...</p>
    <p class="B">...</p>
    <p class="A">...</p>
    <p class="A">...</p>
    <p class="B">...</p>
    ...
  </div>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</stuff>
```

I would like to generate a summary for this, for example:

```
<summary>
  <classes>
    <name>A</name>
    <name>B</name>
    ...
  </classes>
  <classes>
    ...
  </classes>
  ...
</summary>
```

but I can’t quite figure out how to enumerate the classes used by `p` elements here. There might be `C` or more, too.

What XSLT 1 transformation would produce such a summary?

**EDIT:** Based on [TimC’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469354/gather-class-attributes-of-elements-for-a-class-summary#comment-73996005) below I implemented the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="classes" match="p" use="@class" />

  <xsl:template match="stuff">
    <summary>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./div" />
    </summary>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="div">
    <classes>
      <xsl:for-each select="p[count(. | key('classes', @class)[1]) = 1]">
        <name><xsl:value-of select="@class" /></name>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </classes>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works, somewhat. However, for repeating groups of `<div>` elements it will not produce `<name>N</name>` if it has seen `N` in *any* of the previous `<div>` groups.

Is there a way to “constrain” such a grouping to individual `<div>` groups, and repeat it per group?

Comment: As you are using XSLT 1.0 you can use a technique called "Muenchian Grouping" here. Take a look at http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html for a tutorial. The key you could use in your case would be `<xsl:key name="classes" match="p" use="@class" />`

Comment: Muenchian grouping is the proper solution here - unless your processor happens to support http://exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html

Comment: @TimC Thank you for the great link! It _almost_ worked. The `xsl:key` is ok, however I had to use a `<xsl:if test="@class">` inside of the `<xsl:for-each select="p[count(. | key('classes', @class)[1]) = 1]">` or else it would generate empty `<name />` elements for all other elements in the key set.

Comment: You could also try doing `<xsl:for-each select="p[@class][count(. | key('classes', @class)[1]) = 1]">`

Comment: @TimC, thank you for the tips. I’ve elaborated and updated my question based on your suggestion. Please see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select the distinct "classes" per div, then you need someway to uniquely identify each div. One way is to use the `generate-id()` function. You can then define the key like so

```
<xsl:key name="classes" match="p" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @class)" />
```

So rather grouping just by `class` attribute, you include a unique id for the parent `div`

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="classes" match="p" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @class)" />

  <xsl:template match="stuff">
    <summary>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./div" />
    </summary>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="div">
    <classes>
      <xsl:for-each select="p[count(. | key('classes', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @class))[1]) = 1]">
        <name><xsl:value-of select="@class" /></name>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </classes>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```